# Cloning a tr and it is appearing at the top instead of at the placement of the tr defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

My tr is defined inside the table tag like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="customerid">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="stlineitems">
        <label for="stlineitems">Item(s)</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="onlyleft">
        <select name="get_Items" id="get_Items" class="selectItemsList" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Choose Item">
          <option></option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="moveboxleft">
        <input type="text" class="inputwidth form-control rates_input" name="rate_items" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Provide Rate or if not, provide 0 value" />
      </div>
      <br/>
      <div class="nextitem"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="createNewItemTag">New Item</a>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now, I am using the following snippet to create the cloned above code, all work but the placement is not right, I want it to be creating underneath the `tr` tag before this `<div class="nextitem">` tag, not sure what I am doing wrong here

```
$('.createNewItemTag').click(function(){
    var obj = $(this).parents('tr').first(),
    clonedObj = $(obj[0].outerHTML);
    clonedObj.find(".select2-container").remove();
    clonedObj.find('.createNewItemTag').remove();
    clonedObj.find('td').last().append("<a class='removeItem' href='javascript:void(0)';>Remove</a>");
    clonedObj.find(".removeItem").click(function(){
        $(this).parents('tr').first().remove();
    }); 
    console.log(obj);
    obj.parents('table').append(clonedObj);
    initSelect2ForNextItem(clonedObj.find(".selectItemsList").first());
});
```

Comment: `<tr>` element does not contain `.select2-container` element

Comment: Could you provide the jsfiddle link

Comment: Not really clear what problem is. `append()` would put clone at bottom. Need full explanation of what you expect this code to do

Comment: Your table structure is awry. You have divs starting in one td cell and spanning over to some other cells. If you could show how exactly you want the table HTML markup i can possibly generate a solution for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want new cloned `<tr>` elements to be added BEFORE the element with the "new item" tag.

What we are going to do is utilize jQuery's built in `.clone()` method instead of doing it ourself. Once we have the cloned object we use your existing code to remove the *New Item* button and add the *Remove* button.

After we do that we'll utilize jQuery's `.before()` method to insert the new, cloned element before the original object. (You could use `.after()` if you wanted this to be inserted after the original object)

```js
$('.createNewItemTag').click(function(){
    var obj = $(this).parents('tr').first();
    
    var clonedObj = obj.clone();
    clonedObj.find(".select2-container").remove();
    clonedObj.find('.createNewItemTag').remove();
    clonedObj.find('td').last().append("<a class='removeItem' href='javascript:void(0)';>Remove</a>");
    clonedObj.find(".removeItem").click(function(){
        $(this).parents('tr').first().remove();
    }); 

    obj.before(clonedObj);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="customerid">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="stlineitems">
        <label for="stlineitems">Item(s)</label>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="onlyleft">
        <select name="get_Items" id="get_Items" class="selectItemsList" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Choose Item">
          <option></option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="moveboxleft">
        <input type="text" class="inputwidth form-control rates_input" name="rate_items" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Provide Rate or if not, provide 0 value" />
      </div>
      <br/>
      <div class="nextitem"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="createNewItemTag">New Item</a>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You may also want to clear the inputs of the original object so that it is empty after the clone is created. (or clear the inputs of the cloned object, up to you).

References:

- https://api.jquery.com/clone/
- https://api.jquery.com/after/

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

Use `obj.parents('table').find("tr:eq(0)").after(clonedObj);` instead of `obj.parents('table').append(clonedObj);`

```js
$('.createNewItemTag').click(function() {
  var obj = $(this).parents('tr').first(),
    clonedObj = $(obj[0].outerHTML);
  clonedObj.find(".select2-container").remove();
  clonedObj.find('.createNewItemTag').remove();
  clonedObj.find('td').last().append("<a class='removeItem' href='javascript:void(0)';>Remove</a>");
  clonedObj.find(".removeItem").click(function() {
    $(this).parents('tr').first().remove();
  });
  //console.log(obj);
  obj.parents('table').find("tr:eq(0)").after(clonedObj);
  //initSelect2ForNextItem(clonedObj.find(".selectItemsList").first());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="customerid">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="stlineitems">
        <label for="stlineitems">Item(s)</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="onlyleft">
        <select name="get_Items" id="get_Items" class="selectItemsList" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Choose Item">
          <option></option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="moveboxleft">
        <input type="text" class="inputwidth form-control rates_input" name="rate_items" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Provide Rate or if not, provide 0 value" />
      </div>
      <br/>
      <div class="nextitem"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="createNewItemTag">New Item</a></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

> Js Fiddle Demo : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69n5k9jr/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
$(document).on('click', '.createNewItemTag', function() {
  var rw = $(this).parents('tr');
  var ix = rw.index() +1; //remove +1 to insert above curr row
  var obj= rw.clone();
  obj.addClass('newcol').find('td:first-child').text('New Item');
  $('table tr:nth-child('+ix+')').after(obj);
});
```

```css
table{border-collapse:collapse;}
th,td{border:1px solid #ccc;}
.newcol td{background-color:palegreen;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="text" value="customerid"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="stlineitems"><label for="stlineitems">Item(s)</label></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="onlyleft">
        <select>
          <option>Options go here</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="moveboxleft">
        <input type="text" value="Provide Rate" />
      </div>
      <br/>
      <div class="nextitem"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="createNewItemTag">New Item</a>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

Notes:

(1) Switched to using `.on()` to allow newly added rows to be cloned

Comment: This is cool, but few tweeks, Remove link should be there and new item link needs to be shown only once, at the top only